# phpunit: mocking abstract class for type hinting?

Tags: mocking, phpunit

I'm trying to test a helper function which takes some instance of `Form`, an abstract class with a single abstract method, `process` (which isn't actually called from the tested function).

```
function get_field_class(Form $form, $field) {
  return $form->get_errors_for($field) ? 'error' : '';
}
```

My question is, **how can I mock the abstract `Form` class so that it's accepted by `get_field_class`'s type annotation?**

### I've tried passing the mock instance directly:

```
$form = $this->getMockForAbstractClass(Form::class)
  ->method('process')
  ->will($this->returnValue(true));

$this->assertEquals('error', $this->wrapper->get_field_class($form, 'foo'));
```

This throws a TypeError: **Argument 1...must be an instance of Form, instance of PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\Builder\InvocationMocker given**

### I've tried setting the mock class name explicitly:

```
$form = $this->getMockBuilder(Form::class)
  ->setMockClassName(Form::class)
  ->getMockForAbstractClass(Form::class)
  // ...
```

This throws the warning **Class "Form" already exists**. (Warnings are promoted to exceptions or errors in my config, so this isn't an acceptable solutions.)

### I've tried disabling autoloading (maybe phpunit is for some reason eagerly loading the Form class??):

```
$form = $this->getMockBuilder(Form::class)
  ->disableAutoload()
  ->setMockClassName(Form::class)
  ->getMockForAbstractClass(Form::class)
  // ...
```

This just throws the warning: **Class "Form" does not exist.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first example that didn't work, you are not actually passing the mock object.  In order for that to work the code would need to be:

```
$form = $this->getMockForAbstractClass(Form::class);

$form->expects($this->once())
  ->method('process')
  ->will($this->returnValue(true));

$this->assertEquals('error', $this->wrapper->get_field_class($form, 'foo'));
```

`will()` returns an object that PHPUnit uses to verify that mock objects were called properly.

As mentioned in the comments removing `setMockClassName` from the MockBuilder call would work.

```
$form = $this->getMockBuilder(Form::class)
  ->getMockForAbstractClass(Form::class);
```

Again with this form, you would need to set the expectations for the calls to `process` separately.

The error you are getting is because the class already exists and PHP won't let you create two classes with the same name.  You wouldn't need to set the name anyway for this as PHPUnit will be making a new object that extends your `Form` class.

Take a look at the example from the PHPUnit documentation:
https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/7.1/test-doubles.html#mocking-traits-and-abstract-classes

```
<?php
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

abstract class AbstractClass
{
    public function concreteMethod()
    {
        return $this->abstractMethod();
    }

    public abstract function abstractMethod();
}

class AbstractClassTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testConcreteMethod()
    {
        $stub = $this->getMockForAbstractClass(AbstractClass::class);

        $stub->expects($this->any())
             ->method('abstractMethod')
             ->will($this->returnValue(true));

        $this->assertTrue($stub->concreteMethod());
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: That all makes sense. In short, my key mistake was thinking that `will()` is part of the "fluent" interface that returns the stub object. That led me down the more convoluted path involving `setMockClassName()` and friends. Thanks!